# How can I ignore white space when using classList.add?

Tags: javascript, html, css, class

I'm trying to add classes to an element in JS using **classList.add()**, if I have input like this ("one two") separated by whitespace how can I take each part as a class ?

```
let element = document.querySelector(".element")
element.classList.add("one two")
```

Comment: Try it this way `element.classList.add("one", "two")`

Comment: Thank you, but how can I take each part of the input alone, so I can assign it to multiple elements?

Comment: You mean to use these 2 classes for other elements as well? Please give me an example

Comment: I will take a class name from the user as an input, It's easy to deal with a one-word class, but if the user enters two words or more like ("one two three"), how can I consider each word as a class?

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add multiple classes into an element:

```
element.classList.add("one", "two");
```

or

```
element.classList.add("two"); 
element.classList.add("one");
```

To use classes from an input, seperated by space:

```
const userInput = "one two";
element.classList.add(...userInput.split(" "));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const str = 'one two three';
const classes = str.split(' ');
document.querySelector(".element").classList.add(...classes);
```